# How do I convert an OpenSSH-generated ED25519 key to the PEM format?

Tags: openssh, key-authentication, dropbear

I am trying to convert an OpenSSH-generated private host key to the PEM format, so that I can use it also in `dropbear-initramfs`. However, when trying to do so using the `ssh-keygen` program, I am getting an error as follows:

```
…# ssh-keygen -m PEM -e -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key >/root/ssh_host_ed25519_key
do_convert_to_pem: unsupported key type ED25519
```

How can I perform this operation?

Answer (score -1):

It turns out while the `-e` (*export*) option fails to do so, convertion in place works just fine. You can do as follows:

```
…# cp /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key /root/ssh_host_ed25519_key
…# ssh-keygen -m PEM -p -f /root/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Key has comment 'root@…'
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but on private ssh key generated like this: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`, unfortunately (at least in this case) it does not look like convertion in place will result in PEM format. The resulting format seems to be the same as original openssh format.

Comment: Nope, doesn't look like it here either. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/267767/299537